# Search for websites with a common XML tag

Tags: html, automation, web-crawler

I'm looking to isolate a list of websites that have been constructed using a common template.

i.e. - All the websites will contain the following tag in their page HTML:

`<div id="calas">Powered by <a href="http://www.calas.co.uk" title="Car Leasing Broker websites and software.">CALAS</a></div>`

Is this possible?